# How to add string with URL :: to in laravel function?

Tags: php

I have the code seen below:

```
 $arrlink = '<a href='.'"{{URL::to('."'/edit-customer/'".$customer->customer_id.')}}"'.'><i style='.'"color: green; margin: 5px;"'.' class='.'"far fa-edit"'.'></i></a>';
```

How do I add a string with URL :: to a laravel function?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What do you mean by "URL ::"?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use concatenation in blade

```
$arrlink = '<a href="'.url("edit-customer/{$customer->customer_id}").'"><i style="color: green; margin: 5px;" class="far fa-edit"></i></a>';
```

Comment: I can not fix it

Comment: what's issue? are you using it in blade?

Comment: i using it in lavarel. The generated URL is faulty

Comment: what is generated url?

Comment: echo $arrlink on browser

Comment: Updated my answer now try